# Building Android 11 for x86 with ARM compatibility

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, android-virtual-device

Earlier this year, Google published the new Android 11 x86 system images with ARM compatibility.

According to what is written in this [article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/03/run-arm-apps-on-android-emulator.html), these new ARM-compatible Android 11 system images allow the entire system to run x86 natively, while applications that required ARM binary would be translated exclusively to ARM within the process context which naturally leads to better performance than using a full-ARM system image.

My question is this - I want to compile my customized Android 11 from sources for x86. Is there a way to build an image that utilizes these ABIs that intermediate between an ARM based app and the operating system similar to Google's published system images?

Answer (score 0):

This was achieved in previous releases also using libhoudini from intel , also the reason apps with arm Native could work on x86 devices. Android-11 emulator have Arm provided emulation(Arm to x-86) libs. Any such solution can be hooked via Android Runtime interface called NativeBridge. All the android native calls from app native library will be routed to arm libs loaded and running in emulation environment.

For example, NativeBridge will load Main Emulation Library for creating Emulation Environment and there will be associated arm libraries for android accompanying main emulation library. So any call from android app's Native Arm library will go to Main Emulation library, which in turn will load associated android Arm Native library, emulate(arm to x86) and execute native android code.

Definitely it is not the complete answer to your question.